# what are the skills required for a SharePoint UI/UX Developer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

What are the skills required for becoming a SharePoint UI Developer. What tools and applications will be used in developing UI.

Comment: If you're moving into UX (which isn't the same as UI) take a look at the following post: [As a programmer, how do I move into User Experience Design?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/as-a-programmer-how-do-i-move-into-user-experience-design)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most that a developer would use:

**Visual Studios**

create pritty much anything that you cant do out of the box from webparts to custom workflows/event handlers

**Sharepoint Designer**

this is one of the big tools, here you can customise the site accordingly through that aspx pages including masterpage and css

**Css / javascript**

this plays a vital role in colour and placing controls in required location

**theory**

required for the assesment on building the design and requirements gathering. This includes requirement gathering, UI constrains, UI requirements, Company scheme and colours, utilising multiple diagrams like DFD, ERD, UI limitation vs requirments and the list goes on...

the teory is the first stage in building a UX/UI report. From this you would then develop a UX/UI interface and from both the report and interface you can build using the methods above!